# Raw Transaction: GasPrice, Limit in Hex or Decimal?

Tags: web3js, ethereumjs, raw-transaction

When signing a raw Transaction like this: (example taken from Javascript API Docs)

```
var Tx = require('ethereumjs-tx');
var privateKey = new Buffer('e331b6d698.......................23123', 'hex')

var rawTx = {
  nonce: '0x00',
  gasPrice: '0x09184e72a000', 
  gasLimit: '0x2710',
  to: ' 0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000', 
  value: '0x00', 
  data: '0x7f7465737432000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000600057'
}

var tx = new Tx(rawTx);
tx.sign(privateKey);

var serializedTx = tx.serialize();

web3.eth.sendRawTransaction('0x' + serializedTx.toString('hex'), function(err, hash) {
  if (!err)
    console.log(hash); // "0x7f9fade1c0d57a7af66ab4ead79fade1c0d57a7af66ab4ead7c2c2eb7b11a91385"
});
```

It seems like it works to pass gasPrice and gasLimit in hex and decimal numbers. Why does it work? Does this work for every field (like nonce and value)?